# How to deploy a portlet in an already deployed Application?

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic, portlet

The client already has his application deployed on an weblogic server and now we have to add a new portlet in it. But we can not give the whole application to our client for deployment. We must give him a some kind of plugin.

So which are the possible approaches? How can we deploy a portlet in an already deployed Application?

I'm using Web logic 10.3.0.0 on Windows-XP.

---

I have tried following the steps described in [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/prodOps/deployment.html). But When I access my newly deployed application it gives following error:

```
<Error> <J2EE Deployment SPI> <BEA-260101> <Parameter 'DDBeanRoot' may not be null.>
```

To resolve this I have tried following solutions but did not worked for me:

- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=827531 (There is no annotation-manifest.xml in my war file)
- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=940332 (Can not find the patch)
- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=727141 (there is no extra ; in my xml files)

---

If I deploy EAR file for my new portlet, I'm able to access its wsdl in portal admin console. But in this I'm not able to see the portals, pages, books in this application. Now even if I add new portals, desktops, pages, portlets in the admin console, I am not able to see those portals by its generated url. I get 404, Page Not Found for the urls.

The generated url looks like `http://localhost:7001/DeployTestWeb/appmanager/qwerty.portal/qwerty` where `qwerty.portal` is the new portal I have created and `qwerty` at the is desktop of this portal.

---

So there are 2 issues in this, First "*How can I successfully import my war file and access it without any error?*" and another is "*After successful import how can I include the new portlet in existing portals of application?*"

Answer (score 0):

Is this on a Weblogic Portal running with JSR 168 compliance?

If so, it is possible to deliver a JSR 168 compliant Portlet as an independent war and import it into the target environment after registering the WAR as a WSRP Portlet Producer.

See more at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/prodOps/deployment.html

Comment: I have successfully import the war file but now how can I test it? I do not understand the *Accessing the Portlets* part of the document.

Comment: @HarryJoy: now you need to register the web app containing your portelt as a WSRP Producer, see the steps at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/federation/Chap-Details.html#wp1021410

Comment: I'm getting this error: `<Error> <J2EE Deployment SPI> <BEA-260101> <Parameter 'DDBeanRoot' may not be null.>` When trying to access the new deployed application.

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=827531 I think some portlet XML from the old war is not compatible in the new WLS

Comment: I can not find `annotation-manifest.xml` in my war file. I also checked `web.xml`, there is no extra `;` in it. I also tried to find patch described in here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=940332 , but can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

no need WSRP hassle here. You can create war app with new portlet, deploy it as "weblogic shared library". After this in Portal Administration App you will get portlet you created in library definitions. So if you client use streaming desktop he can customize any page by adding new portlet to it.